# For which planes do Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) regulations apply?

Tags: usa, air-travel, regulations

For which planes do [Federal Aviation Administration (FAA)](https://www.faa.gov/) regulations apply? Do they apply to all planes entering the United States and all planes departing the United States? Do they also apply to planes registered in the United States but flying between airports outside the United States?

Comment: I suspect you're looking for our sister site [aviation.se].

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, I am ok to move the question there if it is more on topic on aviation. The reason why I posted the question on Travel is that travelers sometime look for regulations that apply to their planes (e.g. regulations purtaining to portable batteries in carry-on luggage).

Comment: OK, that might be more of a travel question. I'm not entirely 100% sure where the best place is now.

Comment: @downvoter: please explain your downvote and I would be happy to enhance the question.

Comment: Rules about carrying batteries may involve the FAA, or (more likely IMO) the TSA and DHS. The common thread is Aviation, so I agree with @MichaelHampton that  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/ is a better site.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica AFAIK rules about carrying batteries come from FAA, e.g. see https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/lithium-batteries-more-100-watt-hours: the TSA points to FAA.

Comment: Yes, that page does refer to the FAA. But that page doesn't support the conclusion that TSA/DHS gets its/their security judgments _solely_ from the FAA. For that reason, I think your question would be better on Aviation.

Comment: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6430/1810

Comment: Different FAA regulations will apply to certain planes for different reasons.  Some may apply because the plane is registered in the US.  Others may apply because the plane is owned by a US carrier or by a foreign carrier approved to operate in the US.  Others may apply because the plane is built in the US.  Others may apply because the plane is flying through US airspace.  I am going to vote to close as too broad, but the question should be easily answerable (and on topic here) if you change it to "which planes are affected by [that specific FAA regulation cited by TSA] and why?"

Comment: I'm going to answer on the assumption that you will so edit the question.

Comment: @phoog thanks for the information this is great to know. It's not obvious to many people that which planes are in the impacted by FAA regulations depend on which FAA regulation one considers. Why closing the question instead of converting your comment into an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about aviation rules that do not apply to the general traveller.

Comment: I *did* convert my comment to an answer.  I will retract my close vote if you edit the question as I suggest.  As it is, it's too broad and not obviously on topic.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, you say that you're interested in the FAA regulation cited by the TSA in its page on airline passengers carrying lithium batteries in their luggage.  That regulation is [49 CFR 175.10(a)(18)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/175.10#a_18).  It basically applies to any aircraft flying to, from, or within the US, and all aircraft registered in the US, with some exceptions noted below, and perhaps some other exceptions that I have not identified.

The scope of the regulation is given in [49 CFR 175.1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/175.1), which defines "Purpose, scope and applicability" for all of 49 CFR 175:

> § 175.1 Purpose, scope and applicability.
>
> (a) This part prescribes requirements that apply to the transportation of hazardous materials in commerce aboard (including attached to or suspended from) aircraft. The requirements in this part are in addition to other requirements contained in parts 171, 172, 173, 178, and 180 of this subchapter.
>
> (b) This part applies to the offering, acceptance, and transportation of hazardous materials in commerce by aircraft to, from, or within the United States, and to any aircraft of United States registry anywhere in air commerce. This subchapter applies to any person who performs, attempts to perform, or is required to perform any function subject to this subchapter, including -
>
> (1) Air carriers, indirect air carriers, and freight forwarders and their flight and non-flight employees, agents, subsidiary and contract personnel (including cargo, passenger and baggage acceptance, handling, loading and unloading personnel); and
>
> (2) Air passengers that carry any hazardous material on their person or in their carry-on or checked baggage.
>
> (c) This part does not apply to aircraft of United States registry under lease to and operated by foreign nationals outside the United States if:
>
> (1) Hazardous materials forbidden aboard aircraft by § 172.101 of this subchapter are not carried on the aircraft; and
>
> (2) Other hazardous materials are carried in accordance with the regulations of the State (nation) of the aircraft operator.
>
> (d) The requirements of this subchapter do not apply to transportation of hazardous material in support of dedicated air ambulance, firefighting, or search and rescue operations performed in compliance with the operator requirements under federal air regulations, title 14 of the CFR.

For reference, "commerce" is defined at [49 CFR 171.8](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/171.8) as

> trade or transportation in the jurisdiction of the United States within a single state; between a place in a state and a place outside of the state; that affects trade or transportation between a place in a state and place outside of the state; or on a United States-registered aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in a comment from [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog):

> Different FAA regulations will apply to certain planes for different reasons. Some may apply because the plane is registered in the US. Others may apply because the plane is owned by a US carrier or by a foreign carrier approved to operate in the US. Others may apply because the plane is built in the US. Others may apply because the plane is flying through US airspace.

Comment: @phoog I'll remove this answer if you add this information to your answer.

Comment: I didn't include this in my answer because I didn't have time to identify a specific FAA regulation with different scope.  Furthermore, given that this is [Travel.SE], I would only want to use a regulation that has some visibility to commercial air passengers, which would make it even more time consuming to identify a suitable regulation.